# ASP.NET Core can't step into endpoint method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API controller with a method like so:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/api/groups/{groupId}/feeds/{feedItemId}/flag")]
    [FeedItemAccess(AccessLevelTypes.GroupMember, "groupId")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FlagFeedItem([FromRoute] int groupId, [FromRoute] long feedItemId)
    {
        try
        {
            await _feedManagementService.FlagMessage(groupId, feedItemId);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "FlagFeedItem(int)");
            return new OopsResult(ex);
        }
    }
```

I put breakpoints on the `await` line and on the `_logger` line.  I then use my REST client to hit the specified endpoint (http://myhost/api/groups/1/feeds/1/flag) in debug mode.

I immediately get back a blank 200 response... but the await method is never hit, nor is the service underneath, and I never reach the breakpoint(s).  I'm scratching my head on this.  I would think this was a thread deadlocking issue but for the fact that it actually returns a 200 status code.

What could be the problem here?  The routing appears to be correct, I can intercept on the controller's constructor, all looks fine... but when it gets here, the system just decides it doesn't actually need to do anything.

BTW, the `FeedItemAccess` filter just checks the user's tenancy rights to connect to the endpoint; it also appears to be working fine (I can intercept on that too and it's leaving the filter under success conditions).

Comment: Have you tried the old "restart Visual Studio" and "clean solution"?

Comment: yeah... though I'm about to try "restart the computer and/ or drop it in the ocean" next... it's just this one endpoint.  Makes no sense.

Comment: If you change the route attribute but use the same URL, does it still give you HTTP 200?

Comment: What happens if you comment out `[FeedItemAccess(AccessLevelTypes.GroupMember, "groupId")]`?

Comment: @DavidG if I change the route but use the same url, it gives a 404.

Comment: @mjwills wow... I'm getting a success out of the access attribute, but if I comment it out I hit the breakpoint.... hmm.  There's nothing in the filter that returns a 200, so I'll have to figure that out now.

Comment: Well, clearly it is **something** to do with that attribute.

Comment: yup... now I just have to figure out why.  Thanks, I'm not blocked any more.  I thought for sure that wasn't the problem because it was doing what I intended it to do... seems like I intended it to break my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mjwills suggested, I should have been a bit more careful in dismissing what could or could not cause this behavior.  I had thought I understood how the action filter was supposed to behave, and since it seemed to be doing what I wanted, I *knew* it wasn't the problem... but it actually was.

Removing all possible culprits and methodically adding them back in... sometimes it's the only way to find the problem.